# 400 Bad Request when adding utf-8 charset to POST request

Tags: curl, asana

I've build an API client based on Guzzle that since version 3.4.2 adds an utf-8 charset to the Content-Type header. With this header the Asana API returns a 400 Bad Request error, while without the charset things work fine.

This doesn't work on POST and PUT requests:

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8

This works:

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;

Using curl as the simplest example :

This one fails:

```
curl -u {apikey}: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects -d "name=Test" -d "notes=Test." -d "workspace={workspace-id}" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
```

Returns a 400 Bad Request with this output :

> {"errors":[{"message":"Request data must be a JSON object, not null"}]}

This one succeeds:

```
curl -u {apikey}: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects -d "name=Test" -d "notes=Test." -d "workspace={workspace-id}" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"
```

This returns a 201 created with the data that was send.

This happens for other POST and PUT requests as well. 
Is this a bug in the Asana API or expected behaviour?

Comment: (I work at Asana.) This may be a bug in our system. We'll investigate and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I work at Asana.) We've verified this is a bug. The fix should be live in the next day or so. Thanks for reporting!